# Meteor - Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to establish a connection between my Meteor application and my MongoDB Atlas database.

I have the following bit of JavaScript:

```
  var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient, format = require('util').format;                  
MongoClient.connect('<MyMongoURL>', function (err, db) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
} else {
    console.log("successfully connected to the database");

    db.collection('largeTreeMap', function(err, docs) {
    // Check for error
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    // Walk through the cursor
    docs.find().each(function(err, doc) {
        // Check for error
        if(err) return console.err;
        // Log document
        console.log(doc);
    })
});

}
db.close();      });
```

I added this to a blank JS document called test.js and upon running

```
node test.js
```

In my command line it returned the success message and data:

[image: Success]

So now that I know the connection can be established I added the code to my Meteor project. I created a basic button and onClick the connection to MongoDB should completed.

However, instead I receive the following console error:

[image: Error]

I understand from reading various Stack questions that this is a result of not running `npm install mongodb` in the project directory. However, I have tried doing this and the terminal returns:

[image: Error 2]

Does any body know why the MongoDB is failing to install and preventing me from connecting to MongoDB in my application?

Any help would be much appreciated,

Many thanks,

G

Comment: meteor uses there own version of mongodb internally. Maybe this causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to connect to the Mongo instance from the *client*, which is probably not what you want.

The [`mongodb`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) npm package supports only Node.js, not JavaScript in the browser, as you can see from this line in its [`package.json`](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/package.json)

```
"engines": {
  "node": ">=0.10.3"
},
```

In the case that worked, you are running it with Node.

What you probably want to do is to set the [`MONGO_URL`](https://docs.meteor.com/environment-variables.html#MONGO-URL) environment variable to the Mongo Atlas instance, and leave the implementation of connecting / updating to Meteor itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - Do you know if setting the MONGO_URL in the settings.json file would be enough to connect?

Comment: No they are different things - the settings you set in `settings.json` is accessed via `Meteor.settings`, this is different from environment variables, which are accessed via `process.env`.

Comment: I am having the same problem when running puppeteer in the browser using browserify, if anyone knows how to solve this, please help.

Comment: @coder420 I don't understand your exact use case but running `puppeteer` on the client seems like a mistake or at least a bad design. `puppeteer` is typically ran on the server, even if that server is your local development machine. Think of it another way - it'd be a terrible user experience to have the end-user download hundreds of MBs of various browsers to test on.